# What does vm prefix mean in the address line?

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

I'm going through the [Apache ActiveMQ example](http://activemq.apache.org/hello-world.html) and faced the `vm` prefix as follows:

```
ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = 
                   new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("vm://localhost");
```

What does that mean? By the way, when I connect to the mesasge broker I basically use an address like `tcp://localhost:61616`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although Rahul is correct, I think it makes sense to add some context to the answer.

So, *vm* stands for *virtual machine*, which is a very central concept in Java. Java programs execute in the virtual machine.

More information about your particular ActiveMQ case, explaining the difference between *vm://* and *tcp://*, can be read about [here](http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-embed-a-broker-inside-a-connection.html):

> In the same JVM clients can then use the *vm://* transport to connect to the embedded broker - whilst external clients can use the *tcp://* protocol

Comment: So if we specify the vm prefix we actually create the instance of the broker from the `apachemq` jar, right?

Comment: @user3663882 I am not an ActiveMQ expert, but basically you are just specifying the transport. VM transport should be quicker since it doesn't need to be transported over the network, it is doing the communication inside the virtual machine.

Comment: I mean it can be useful if we need to comunicate with the parts of an application running on a single vm.

Answer (score 2):

VM stands for Virtual Machine.

Answer (score 2):

It stands for a VM (Virtual Machine) your connecting to.

You can read more about it in their [docs](http://activemq.apache.org/vm-protocol.html).